# Twitter gem sample app with OAuth2

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, twitter, oauth-2.0, twitter-gem

I'm trying to get my app to work with the twitter gem, but I can't seem to perform the authorization protocol using OAuth2. I'd like to know if there is a sample app available so I can see what I'm doing wrong.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what authentication engine is used by you, but here are some examples with omniauth + devise gem.

https://github.com/holden/devise-omniauth-example

https://github.com/bradrobertson/devise-omniauth-example

https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/Example-Applications

Comment: Maybe my question wasn't very clear, but what I meant was that I needed some examples on how to perform the authorization protocol of OAuth2 so I could use the Twitter API. Apparently the Twitter gem used to come with a Twitter::OAuth class, which is no longer the case. The authentication must be done separately using the oauth2 gem. If you could point out some examples meant to be used with the twitter gem, it would be very kind of you. Thanks.

Comment: You can use devise + omiauth with twitter. Links above contains some examples)

Answer (score 0):

I maintain a sample app that demonstrates how to use the "Sign in with Twitter" workflow using the twitter gem and OmniAuth. You should be able to figure it out by looking at that.

https://github.com/sferik/sign-in-with-twitter